# manufacturers serial number of the hard drive

Tags: 12.04, gnome-terminal

I need to get manufacturers serial number of the hard drive.

In windows I got following results,

```
C:\>wmic diskdrive get serialnumber
SerialNumber
2020202057202d44435759415255393XXXXXXXXX
```

How can I check this from Ubuntu terminal ?

**Edited :**

When I used `hdparm -i /dev/sda` command its giving OS given id, not the manufacturers id. it is similar to windows command `vol c:`.

But in my case I need to find the 40 digits `manufactures serial number`.

Comment: [Several different answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364496/274507)

Answer (score 6):

Try this command to get the Serial Number only,

```
sudo hdparm -i /dev/sda | grep -oE 'SerialNo=.*'
```

Where `/dev/sda` is my Harddisk.

Example:

```
$ sudo hdparm -i /dev/sda | grep -oE 'SerialNo=.*'
SerialNo=S2SMJ9CD201346
```

**OR**

Try the below command to view the serial number of your Hard-disk (In my case it's `/dev/sda`).

```
$ sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda | grep -E 'Serial\ Number'
Serial Number:    S2SMJ9CD201346
```

Before running the above command, you have to install `smartmontools` package.

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
```

Comment: Note that with current Western Digital drives the serial number will have a `WD-` prefix to the manufacturers recognized serial number.

Comment: Nice, `smartctl` works for me. How do i find the serial nos for all the hard drives using 1 command? Possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to retrieve the serial number of your hard disk.
One of these is to use `hdparm`.
Typing:

```
 sudo hdparm -i /dev/sda
```

you can read some information about the first hard disk. If you want to inspect another device, type `sudo fdisk-l` to retrieve the path of the other devices connected.

Comment: This is not what i need, I have updated my question .